# how can I write right to left language in netbeans 7.2

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

[image: my problem]

i had problem with netbeans 7.2,

my language is right to left. please help me to correct this.

as the photo show's html codes had bad display.

Comment: my codes work correct but have wrong display!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem solved by change NetBeans Theme(Tools > Option -> Fonts & Color -> Profile).

Thanks NetBeans For Very Nice App.